# How can I create a custom ajax callback command?

Tags: 8, ajax

I found different type of ajax commands like htmlCommand, invoke command etc. I want to create a custom ajax command that sets the response of ajax callback as the value of specifying markup in the callback argument. Is it possible? I created one as [per this tutorial](http://mike-miles.com/blog/creating-ajax-callback-commands-drupal-8).

```
    public function ajax_call_back_function() {
       $response = new AjaxResponse();
       $element  = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
       $returnDelta = $element['#array_parents'][2]; // get levels
       $delta = $element['#value']; // eg : 944 THis is the ata i want to set as the value of markup
       $response->addCommand(new ReadMessageCommand($delta, $returnDelta));
       return $response;
    }
```

The `ReadMessageCommand` class is the following.

```
    class ReadMessageCommand implements CommandInterface {
      protected $message;
      // Constructs a ReadMessageCommand object.
      public function __construct($message,$level) {
      $this->message = $message;
      $this->level = $level;
      }
     // Implements Drupal\Core\Ajax\CommandInterface:render().
    public function render() {
       return array(
      'command' => 'readMessage',
      'message' => $this->message,
      'level' => $this->level,  
     );
   }
  }
```

I include a JavaScript file.

```
    (function($, Drupal) {
      Drupal.AjaxCommands.prototype.readMessage = function(ajax, response, status){
      $('#edit-field-region-management-'+response.level+'-valueregion').val(response.message);
     };
    })(jQuery, Drupal);
```

The controller class is the following.

```
   class AjaxCommandsAddController extends ControllerBase {
     public function messagesPage() {
       $page[] = array(
         '#type' => 'markup',
         '#markup' => $content,
     );
// Attach JavaScript library.
       $page['#attached']['library'][] = wms_ajax_commands/wms_ajax_commands.commands';
       return $page;
      }
    }
```

But when executing, I get the following error.

> Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\Core\Ajax\ReadMessageCommand' not found in Path-to-module/src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/RegionWidgetType.php

Comment: Use  a wrapper element. Where are you calling your ajax_callback_function()?

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you have a namespace error(s). The error happens in a file you didn't mention `RegionWidgetType.php`. It's trying to use `Drupal\Core\Ajax\ReadMessageCommand` which as I understand it is something you made. Which means that the namespace should definitely not be `\DrupalCore\...` for the auto load to work.

The name space of your custom files should be `Drupal\MODULE_NAME\folder\structure`